# Java Scanner nextLong check for break lines / blanks

Tags: java

```
private static long getLongInput() {
    while (!scanner.hasNextLong()) {
        System.err.println("please enter a number, no text allowed");
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextLong();
}
```

this piece of code will prevent users from entering text, but the scanner keeps adding blank lines in the console if you push enter without any input. no big deal but I want it to say that you can not enter blanks.

Comment: You miss scanner.nextLin()

Comment: Please enlighten me: next() or nextLine() do the same thing in this context.

Comment: nextLine also reads the EOL char

Comment: Agree but it does not change the behaviour of the scanner. It keeps asking new input. In fact, nextLine() creates others issues down the lane.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long getLongInput() {
    while (!scanner.hasNextLong()) {
        System.err.println("please enter a number, no text allowed");
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextLong();
}

private static long inputAccountNumber() {
    long accountNumber = getLongInput();
    while (!Account.checkAccountNumber(accountNumber)) {
        System.err.println(accountNumber + " is not correct format!");
        accountNumber= getLongInput();
    }
    return accountNumber;
}
```

this is the complete bunch of code which needs to give me a correct account number.